# Netlogo: variable sometimes list sometimes number, results in error

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I have a reporter that works fine when I run it but mistakingly when I add a condition to it.

All my turtles have two three dimensional vectors called `var_a`and `var_b`. When I run this for my whole world there's no problem:

```
to-report turtle-bounds [p]
      let p-lower (([item 0 var_a] of p) - ([item 0 var_b] of p))
      let p-upper (([item 0 var_a] of p) + ([item 0 var_b] of p))
      let bounds list p-lower p-upper
      report bounds
end
```

But when I run it with a condition,

```
to condition
    let p1 turtles with-max [item 0 var_a]
    turtle-bounds p1
end
```

I get the following:

> - expected input to be a number but got the list [0.9967359117803329] instead.

Which is referencing a value of var_a, meaning that my restriction somehow makes the `[item 0 var_a] of p` give a list instead of a number.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `turtle-bounds` is written to take a single agent as its argument, but `with-max` returns an agentset.  I'm not sure why running `turtle-bounds` on an agentset gives that particular error, however.  What happens if in `to-condition` you use `turtle-bounds one-of p1` to reduce the agentset to an agent?  BTW, could p1 have more than one agent in it?

Comment: Hi @Charles, thanks for your comment. I tried your approach and it does work :). In theory it could be that p1 has more than one agent, but since var_1 is assigned randomly, I'd imagine with-max should only select one. I am not an expert but it may be that `turtles` always marks the agentset as a list even if only one is selected and so `one-of` is mandatory in this case... If you'd like to type the answer feel free to do so, otherwise I'll do it myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`turtle-bounds` is written to take a single agent as its argument, but `with-max` returns an agentset. You can turn the agentset into an agent by using the `one-of` primitive before giving p1 to `turtle-bounds`.

```
to condition
    let p1 turtles with-max [item 0 var_a]
    turtle-bounds one-of p1
end
```

Alternatively, you could check `p` in `turtle-bounds` to see if it is an agentset

```
if is-agentset? p [set p one-of p]
```

and make the conversion there, especially if there are other occasions where `turtle-bounds` might be fed an agentset rather than an agent.